# With C# Dev Kit, Invoice Not Appearing In QB

Tags: quickbooks, invoice, intuit-partner-platform, devkit

The code seems to run.  I don't get any error messages, but an invoice does not appear in QB after I sync.  The code is basically this (http://pastebin.com/y7QENxeX) with a few (presumably) minor changes as noted.  I'm able to create Accounts and Customers so I believe the basic infrastructure of my app is good.  I don't understand why I'm stuck on invoices.  I think my customerID is 2.  I only have 5 in my company right now.  And I think my itemID is 1 as I only have one in QB right now.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.PhysicalAddress physicalAddress = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.PhysicalAddress();
physicalAddress.Line1 = "123 Main St.";
physicalAddress.Line2 = "Apt. 12";
physicalAddress.City = "Mountain View";
physicalAddress.CountrySubDivisionCode = "CA";
physicalAddress.Country = "USA";
physicalAddress.PostalCode = "94043";
physicalAddress.Tag = new string[] { "Billing" };

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceHeader();
invoiceHeader.ARAccountId = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.QB, Value = "37" };
invoiceHeader.ARAccountName = "Accounts Receivable";
// original code : invoiceHeader.CustomerId = new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.NG, Value = "3291253" };
invoiceHeader.CustomerId = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.QB, Value = "2" };
invoiceHeader.Balance = (decimal)100.00;
invoiceHeader.BillAddr = physicalAddress;
invoiceHeader.BillEmail = "detroit@tigers.com";
invoiceHeader.CustomerName = "Detroit Tigers";
invoiceHeader.DocNumber = "1234567";
invoiceHeader.DueDate = DateTime.Now;
invoiceHeader.ShipAddr = physicalAddress;
invoiceHeader.ShipDate = DateTime.Now;
invoiceHeader.TaxAmt = (decimal)5;
invoiceHeader.TaxRate = (decimal).05;
invoiceHeader.ToBeEmailed = false;
invoiceHeader.TotalAmt = (decimal)105.00;

List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceLine> listLine = new List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceLine>();

//Loop for multiple invoice lines could be added here
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2[] invoiceItemAttributes = { Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2.ItemId, Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2.UnitPrice, Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2.Qty };
// original code : object[] invoiceItemValues = { new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QB, Value = "5" }, new decimal(33), new decimal(2) };
object[] invoiceItemValues = { new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.QB, Value = "1" }, new decimal(33), new decimal(2) };
var invoiceLine = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceLine();
invoiceLine.Amount = 66;
invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = true;
invoiceLine.Desc = "test " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
invoiceLine.ItemsElementName = invoiceItemAttributes;
invoiceLine.Items = invoiceItemValues;
invoiceLine.ServiceDate = DateTime.Now;
invoiceLine.ServiceDateSpecified = true;
listLine.Add(invoiceLine);

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Invoice invoice = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Invoice();
invoice.Header = invoiceHeader;
invoice.Line = listLine.ToArray();

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Invoice addedInvoice = commonService.Add(invoice);
```

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the following information about how QuickBooks for Windows Sync Manager works, how to see if Sync ran correctly, if objects are in an errored state and how to resolve. It could be any number of things. Once a record is inserted into the cloud, it asynchronously downloads to QuickBooks on the desktop, at which time business logic is applied and records are matched from the cloud to the desktop. If there is an issue, sync manager will show a record of the object that failed, why it failed and the object will now be in an error state. 
At this point you can review the error and take steps to fix, like revert or update and resubmit. Links to the documentation below.

[QuickBooks Sync Manager](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0300_Sync_Manager)
[Data Sync](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0400_Data_Synchronization)
[Objects in Errored State](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects)
[Sync Activity](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncActivity)
[Sync Status](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus)

regards
Jarred

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you Jarred.  I was able to use the IntuitSyncManagerLogger.log file to determine that my Item didn't have an Account associated with it.